# How can I change textures for a MTLLoader.MaterialCreator instance in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to change the texture maps on a MTLLoader.MaterialCreator instance and I can not find and documentation about MTLLoader.MaterialCreator or how to change it's texture map, if someone knows about any documentation that talks about it or how to do this it would be amazing.

After I ran the preload() method I tried to do this:

```
image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah";

mtlInstance.materials[materialName].map.image = image;
```

How ever that didn't seem to change anything (when I loaded it with OBJLoader)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image [into a texture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture) first:

```js
image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah";

let texture = new Texture(image);
mtlInstance.materials[materialName].map = texture;
```